# How to arrange the text and image in one beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I want to arrange my text and images as the following in **one frame in the beamer**.

[image]

Is it possible to place more images under the text, such as **three images or even more**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** the easiest way, but this adapts the width of the image boxes according to the number of boxes (set the counter `\numofboxes` accordingly)

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{numofboxes}
\newcounter{numofgaps}

\newlength{\textsectionwidth}

\newlength{\truetextsectionwidth}
\newlength{\gapwidth}
\newlength{\boxwidth}

\setlength{\gapwidth}{2\tabcolsep}




\setlength{\textsectionwidth}{\textwidth}



\begin{document}

% Set the number of boxes
\setcounter{numofboxes}{2}
\setcounter{numofgaps}{\numexpr\number\value{numofboxes}-1}

% Calculate the boxlengths
\setlength{\truetextsectionwidth}{\textsectionwidth-\number\value{numofgaps}\gapwidth}

\setlength{\boxwidth}{\truetextsectionwidth/\number\value{numofboxes}}


\begin{frame}{A frame with two images}
  \begin{tabular}{*{\number\value{numofboxes}}c}
    \multicolumn{\number\value{numofboxes}}{p{\textsectionwidth}}{%
      \small\blindtext
    }\tabularnewline
   \includegraphics[scale=1,width=\boxwidth]{fig1} &        \includegraphics[scale=0.2,width=\boxwidth]{fig2} \tabularnewline 
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}


\setcounter{numofboxes}{4}
\setcounter{numofgaps}{\numexpr\number\value{numofboxes}-1}

\setlength{\truetextsectionwidth}{\textsectionwidth-\number\value{numofgaps}\gapwidth}

\setlength{\boxwidth}{\truetextsectionwidth/\number\value{numofboxes}}


\begin{frame}{A frame with four images}
  \begin{tabular}{*{\number\value{numofboxes}}c}
    \multicolumn{\number\value{numofboxes}}{p{\textsectionwidth}}{%
      \small\blindtext
    }\tabularnewline
   \includegraphics[scale=1,width=\boxwidth]{fig1} &        \includegraphics[scale=0.2,width=\boxwidth]{fig2} &  \includegraphics[scale=0.2,width=\boxwidth]{fig3} & \includegraphics[scale=0.2,width=\boxwidth]{fig4}  \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code is reusable. However, when I compiled it, I got some warnings: "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available" and "LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences". Is that ok?

Comment: @CodingTheLife: That's ok, in my point of view. The true font sizes and overall widths depend on your choices

Comment: @CodingTheLife: Don't to forget to use the recalculate code if you apply this for more than one frame with different number of images

Comment: Thanks. " \numexpr\number\value{numofboxes}-1" is new for me (I only know the \value command gets the value of numberofboxes counter). I have read the documentation of the calc packages, but I don't get useful information about it.

Comment: @CodingTheLife: You can use `\setcounter{numofgaps}{\number\value{numofbox}}\addtocounter{numofgaps}{-1}` instead

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is use of `textblock` environment with `textblockcolor` option. Change `width=xx\linewidth` if more figurs are desired.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock*}{\linewidth}(1cm,1cm)
\textblockcolor{cyan}
This is a long text.This is a long text.This is a long text.This is a long text.
\vspace{3cm}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{\linewidth}(1cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords)
\centering
\textblockcolor{}
\colorbox{cyan}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=4cm]{example-image-a}}\hfil
\colorbox{cyan}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=4cm]{example-image-b}}\hfil
\colorbox{cyan}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=4cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is OK, and the color boxes in the question are just placeholders for real content.

Comment: Ya, agree. That can be removed easily. Just look nicer in my eyes :-)-.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this, the simplest is likely something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
A bunch of text. A bunch of text. A bunch of text. A bunch of text.  A bunch of text. A bunch of text.
A bunch of text. A bunch of text. A bunch of text. A bunch of text.  A bunch of text. A bunch of text.
A bunch of text. A bunch of text. A bunch of text. A bunch of text.  A bunch of text. A bunch of text.

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,height=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]