# What's the meaning of the command \number and when to use it? And some confusion about the following code

Tags: counters, lengths, dimension-expressions

```
\setcounter{numofgaps}{\numexpr\number\value{numofboxes}-1}
\setlength{\truetextsectionwidth}{\textsectionwidth-\number\value{numofgaps}\gapwidth}
```

The above code is a snippet from the answer of  [How to arrange the text and image in one beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220214/how-to-arrange-the-text-and-image-in-one-beamer-frame).

1. I know the `\numexpr...\relax` pair is for expression evaluation. The above `\setcounter` command doesn't have `\relax` (Does the end of the parenthesis after `-1` in the code `{\numexpr\number\value{numofboxes}-1}` have the same effect?)
2. what is the purpose of the command `\number` (if I don't use it, will something be wrong?)
3. `\number\value{numofgaps}\gapwidth` means numofgaps multiply
   gapwidth, but why not add the `*` symbol stand for multiplication between `\value{numofgaps}` and `\gapwidth`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\number` primitive is not needed in those contexts. But you need `\dimexpr` in `\setlength`, unless you load `calc`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{numofboxes}
\newcounter{numofgaps}
\newlength{\textsectionwidth}
\newlength{\truetextsectionwidth}
\newlength{\gapwidth}

\setlength{\gapwidth}{10pt} % an easy number
\setlength{\textsectionwidth}{300pt} % an easy number
\setcounter{numofboxes}{11} % an easy number

\begin{document}

\setcounter{numofgaps}{\numexpr\value{numofboxes}-1}
\setlength{\truetextsectionwidth}{\dimexpr\textsectionwidth-\value{numofgaps}\gapwidth}

\texttt{numofgaps = \thenumofgaps}

\texttt{\string\truetextsectionwidth = \the\truetextsectionwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside `\numexpr` any `<number>` can be used, and `\value{numofboxes}` fits the syntax of `<number>`.

A length register can be multiplied by a `<factor>` which basically is a `<number>` or an explicit decimal number.

Note that inside `\dimexpr`, something like

```
\number\value{numofgaps}*\gapwidth
```

would be illegal, because an integer multiplier must go *after* the length register; `\gapwidth*\number\value{numofgaps}` would be legal, but is not really needed.

---

The code `\value{counter}` expands to `\csname c@counter\endcsname`, so it's equivalent to `\c@counter`, where `\c@counter` is the name of the integer register allocated when `\newcounter{counter}` is processed. Inside `\numexpr`, any integer register name can be used directly. There's no need to make it into an explicit number by means of `\number`. The construction `\number\value{counter}` has its uses, but is not needed when TeX expects a `<number>`.